# How do I switch a git(hub) repository to point one level up?

Tags: git, github

I have a project called `foo`. On my machine, this project resides as a subfolder of a non-git folder called `foo_container` (i.e, in `foo_container/foo`). `foo` is a git folder, and I have also synced it up to github, and made several changes.

Later, I added more content in other folders under foo_container (like `foo_container\foo_docs`), and want to check in foo_container as my repo from now on. I do not want to lose the git history for `foo`, but am , of course, ok with changes of foo_container being recorded only from now on.

What is the cleanest way to do this? Here are a couple of options that I considered:

Option #1:

```
cd /path/to/foo_container
git init
<rename repository on github from foo to foo_container>
<some git-remote command - I don't know what this should be to switch existing repo>
```

Option #2 (may work, but I suspect I will lose the git history of the `foo` directory)

Delete the old `foo` repo on github, create a new repo called `foo_container`, `git init` in `foo_container` and `git-remote add origin <...foo_container.git>`

I am not sure if either of these approaches will work, and which is better to do.

Comment: 3 answers all telling you to do the same things. That's consensus for you. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks! All slight variants on the same answer, so accepted the answer that had the most detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is good, for you can declare foo as a submodule of foo_container.

But the easiest would be to:

- rename locally `foo` as `foo_container` (so `foo_container/foo_container`)
- `git mv foo_container/foo_container`'s content under a new folder '`foo`' (`foo_container/foo_container/foo`)
- copy `foo_container\foo_docs` in `foo_container/foo_container/foo_docs`: add, and commit and push
- rename GitHub foo repo as `foo_container`
- replace locally foo_container with `foo_container/foo_container`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Move all the stuff in `foo` to a subdirectory called `foo` (so that you'll have `foo/foo` as your actual project). Commit this move.
2. Move everything from `foo_container` into `foo` so that you'll have things like `foo/foo_docs`. Add and commit all of these.
3. Make `foo` the top level `foo_container` directory and drop the old one. i.e. While in `foo_container`, do `mv foo ../foo_container2`, `cd ..`, `rmdir foo_container`, `mv foo_container2 foo_container`.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
cd foo_container/foo
mkdir foo
git mv * foo/
git commit -m "Move foo to subfolder"
```

This winds you up with a structure of...

```
foo_container/
    foo/
        .git/ (git repo data)
        foo/ (actual contents you've been tracking)
    bar/ (other thing you want to add)
```

Then, move all of the stuff that is currently in `foo_container/foo` directly into `foo_container` (including the `.git` directory), leaving you with a structure of...

```
foo_container/
    .git/ (git repo data)
    foo/ (actual contents you were tracking)
    bar/ (other thing you want to add)
```

Now all of the things you had in `foo_container` that weren't `foo` will show up as new files to be added to your git repository, which is now based in `foo_container`, and `foo` will still show up as a folder, and because of the `git mv`, you'll still have the history in older commits.

```
git add bar
git commit -m "Add bar"
git push origin HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having an "and then everything got moved" commit by using [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) to rewrite history:

```
cd /path/to/foo_container/foo
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir foo; git mv -k * foo/ ' HEAD
cd /path/to/foo_container
mv foo/* foo/.git . # and any other hidden files, like .gitignore
git add foo_docs
```

Now your directory looks like:

```
foo_container
├── .git
└── foo
|   └── stuff
└── foo_docs
    └── other stuff
```

And your history looks like this was always the case.

Note: having rewritten history, you will have to add `--force` to your next `git push` command.

Note: before you `git push --force` you should inspect `git log` and make sure nothing's been catastrophized.

Note: as Noufal Ibrahim mentions below, rewriting history will impose extra work on anyone who's pulled the old history.

Comment: Rewriting history though, is a no go if your repository is public (i.e. shared between multiple users).